# VB.NET Application Performance Test

Tags: vb.net, performance, testing

Currently I'm writing a VB.NET app and it's getting big, resulting in its become very slow.

Is there any application (or plug in) that can test the performance in seconds?
I mean, when I click a button and it displays a product, I want to know exactly how long it is gonna take.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio (certain versions) has a built-in code profiler:

- [Find Application Bottlenecks with Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)
- [Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)
- [Analyzing Application Performance by Using Profiling Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx)
- [Visual Studio Profiler Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/)

There is also [EqaTec's](http://www.eqatec.com/) free code profiler (works well).

[**Note**: Big does not necessarily mean slow. Big slowdowns are often caused by code that has a complexity of O(N^2) or greater...]

Comment: +1 for EqaTec's free profiler. The problem was overuse of OnPropertyChanged. Rant: I lose tons of time because of the need to use OnPropertyChanged and debug bindings. Hopefully WinRT or a future .Net or Visual Studio will resolve both productivity wasters.

Answer (score 3):

Built in to visual studio is a profiler. You can find it under Analyze/Launch Performance Wizard.

You can also download a free trial of Ants Profiler (Red-gate.com) or dotTrace (JetBrains.com)

Comment: Thank you alot. I find out that Ants Profiler is powerful.

Comment: We use ANTS Profiler and have found it very useful in finding bottlenecks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use old school tracing.

```
Dim ts = Stopwatch.StartNew

' Your code goes here

' Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        Dim elapsedTime As String = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10)
        Console.WriteLine( "RunTime " + elapsedTime)
```

Comment: But you really should not. I've seen some production code that has tracing like this inserted after every other line, and people still have no clue why things don't work.